# How to check that table has empty rows and then delete them

Tags: mysql

In my SQL tables there are rows where `columnX` has empty value (""). Now i want them i queried to select them and then delete them.

Query like:

```
tables has empty rows

Delete empty rows
```

How can i do this. Any idea

Comment: What does *empty rows* mean? Do you mean where all columns are null? where a particular column is null? Where columns are null or the default value?

Comment: No Not Null only empty

Comment: You wouldn't need to check first.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok Try this, i hope u'll find your solution

What you need is, first get empty rows

```
Select * From table_name Where column_name = "";
```

Then Delete the empty rows

```
Delete From table_name Where column_name = "";
```

or don't write the select query only write the delete query

I hope this solve your problem

Comment: exactly what i need ... because first i check then i delete

Comment: The select is totally pointless if you are always going to delete. What are you trying to prevent, deleting 0 rows?

Comment: the question is that he first check the empty rows then he delete rows

Answer (score 4):

Depending on what exactly you mean by "empty" rows:

```
delete from yourTable where column1 is null
```

will delete where column1 has a null value. If you mean where multiple columns have nulls, it's just a matter of adding more conditions to the where clause:

```
delete from yourTable where column1 is null and column2 is null and column3 is null
```

If by empty you mean "has spaces in a text field or the field is empty" you can use some of the builtin functions to find them for example:

```
delete from yourTable where trim(column1)=''
```

which would find a row in the table where column1 only has white space in it and so on.

You might want to have a read of [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12475850/how-can-an-sql-query-return-data-from-multiple-tables) that I wrote on SQL, join and the like - it has got a fair bit in it about selecting the right rows from the table - and in your case, replace the `select.... from where...` with a `delete from where...`

Having said all that, I would really wonder *why* you are inserting data into your table that you don't want in it?

Answer (score 2):

You can check each field for null or the empty string like this:

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE (column1 IS NULL OR column1 = '') AND (column2 IS NULL OR column2 = '')
```

Just add the rest of your columns to the `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 1):

Simple : `delete from Test_table where c1 is null,....and cN is null`